# Matplotlib drawing a line with a hint through a plot

Tags: matplotlib

I have a pcolor in matplotlib where I would like to draw a horizontal line with a caption.

So in a way, as it is drawn on the following picture:

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: A line: `ax.axhline`. A caption: `ax.annotate`

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks a lot! Can you write an answer with a little example so that I can accept your answer?